# how to add timestamp to file names when moving them to cloud storage using cron job in ssh

Tags: ssh, cron, crontab, cronjob, google-cloud-storage

I have built an ftp server on google compute engine that receives data from on prem systems as csv. I want to move this data after receiving it to a google cloud storage using a cron job from the vm ssh. in addition to that I want to add the timestamp to the file name when moving it to the storage bucket.

what I have tried as a cron job is

```
*/2 * * * * gsutil mv *.txt gs://univer-bucket/$(date).txt
```

but the job did not work and I don't know how to keep the old name and just add to it the timestamp

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `mv` command says something like "move all files with `.txt` extension to the `gs://univer-bucket/$(date).txt`". This would work only if the `gs://univer-bucket/$(date).txt` is folder, which I assume isn't.

You need to run `mv` for each individual file using `for` loop. Also I would recommend you to specify format of the date for the `date` command.

Resulting line in the crontab could be:

```
*/2 * * * * for file in *.txt; do gsutil mv "$file" "gs://univer-bucket/$(date +%Y-%M-%d-%H%M)-$file.txt"; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) :)